# Can only access google after removing pihole

Tags: networking

I recently tried to install pihole on my ubuntu laptop. After fiddling with it a bit I couldn't get it to work and uninstalled it.

Since then, I have not been able to access any website aside from Google and its derivatives (youtube, etc), which I find very strange.

Even stranger, if I do the command

```
service network-manager restart
```

I can access any site i want for a very short time.

I cannot install anything using apt.

I can provide further info if needed (posting from my phone but the computer is right in front of me).

I am using my computer on campus, but configured the pihole on my home network, so I don't think it has anything to do with my router settings.

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong or how to fix it?

Output from trying to ping amazon:

```
ping -c5 www.amazon.com

PING opf-www.amazon.com (54.239.17.7) 56(84) bytes of data.

From 192.168.0.36 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

From 192.168.0.36 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable

From 192.168.0.36 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

From 192.168.0.36 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable

From 192.168.0.36 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable


--- opf-www.amazon.com ping statistics ---

5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +5 errors, 100% packet loss, time 4017ms

pipe 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem today, which was a DNS problem, solved by editing

> nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base

like so `nameserver 192.168.1.1` for your Routers DNS-Server or `nameserver 8.8.8.8` for Google's DNS-Server for example.

This creates permanent changes in `/etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use their `uninstall.sh` script otherwise it probably wont' disable the various iptable and firewall rules it uses to redirect network activity.

If you've already ran the `uninstall.sh` script and the problem stays around you will need to check `iptables -L` to see what firewall rules still exist and remove them, possibly within `ufw` if that's being used.

Comment: Thanks much for your response. I did uninstall it using their script. I'm certainly not am expert in networks, but the iptables -L command doesn't reveal anything obvious to me; it looks empty

Comment: Try running `sudo service networking restart` as well since it might have changed how interfaces are used. Also looking at their Github their uninstall.sh has been updated very recently: https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/pull/970

Comment: Also see https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/issues/868

Comment: Command had no effect on the problem. This happened last night so it should have been their most recent script, which they seem to acknowledge isn't great in that other thread

Comment: I mention it because that script has been modified in the last few days, so it's likely things missing from the uninstall.sh. Either way can you try running `sudo ufw status` and seeing if there are any weird rules in there somewhat similar to `sudo iptables -L` it could be used to redirect traffic

Comment: Ufw is disabled

Comment: Try using the network manager to delete your existing connection and re-create it, or manually edit it so that it's not using the DNS configuration of pi-hole. Assuming this doesn't work please check your /etc/resolve.conf doesn't have the pi-hole settings in it

Comment: No dice. Thanks much for your responses, I think I'll just reinstall ubuntu

Comment: I looked at their install script: https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/blob/master/automated%20install/basic-install.sh

Try running `sudo apt-get purge network-manager dnsmasq` then `sudo apt-get install network-manager dnsmasq --reinstall`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'm not sure why I didn't see this last one. i ended up reinstalling my os, so i can't test this last suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I use pfBlocker on my home network, it's a DNS blocking utility much like pihole. The lists that I use to tell it what IPs to block can be a bit overzealous at times. I've had to continually add broken sites to a whitelist so they arent blocked. That's kind of what you have to do to avoid false positives.